# Why does as_tibble() round floats to the nearest integer?

Tags: r, dplyr, tibble

When using as_tibble in dplyr 0.7.4 and R 3.4.1 I get the following outputs

```
mtcars %>% aggregate(disp ~ cyl, data=., mean) %>% as_tibble()
```

which outputs

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl  disp
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  4.00   105
2  6.00   183
3  8.00   353
```

while

```
mtcars %>% aggregate(disp ~ cyl, data=., mean)
```

outputs

```
  cyl     disp
1   4 105.1364
2   6 183.3143
3   8 353.1000
```

Not really surprisingly, the following

```
mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(disp=mean(disp))
```

gives again

```
# A tibble: 3 x 2
    cyl  disp
  <dbl> <dbl>
1  4.00   105
2  6.00   183
3  8.00   353
```

Why is this rounding happening and how can I avoid it?

Comment: Try `mtcars %>% group_by(cyl) %>% summarise(disp=mean(disp)) %>% print.data.frame()`.

Comment: Is there a dplyr option for the same result (ie not pretty floating point numbers in console output)?

Answer (score 19):

This is not a rounding, it's only a way for {tibble} to display data in a pretty way:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   aggregate(disp ~ cyl, data=., mean) %>% 
+   as_tibble() %>% 
+   pull(disp)
[1] 105.1364 183.3143 353.1000
```

If you want to see more digits, you have to print a data.frame:

```
> mtcars %>% 
+   aggregate(disp ~ cyl, data=., mean) %>% 
+   as_tibble() %>% 
+   as.data.frame()
  cyl     disp
1   4 105.1364
2   6 183.3143
3   8 353.1000
```

(and yes, the two last lines are useless)

Comment: I see. It's pretty ok but could potentially be misleading in case of quick "on the fly" analysis. Is there a dplyr option to avoid it?

Comment: Why do you have to stick with a tibble when you want the output that a data.frame gives you? It doesn't change the underlying data, so it must be about presentation. If that's the case, then there are some more involved packages for tables like kableExtra, which are applied to the kable() function from knitr.

Comment: @SpencerCastro As I said, it's useless in a script. Here it's just to show that the data don't change with `as_tibble()`.

Comment: The "issue" (if we call it an issue) is when using summarise for instance. I do not use as_tibble but I get a tibble back, as expected. Anyway, ok, I can use as.data.frame in case of need.